# os.environ.get() returns None with Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, environment-variables

I'm working directly from the Cloud Functions UI. I'm creating a new function. In the section `BUILD` I'm adding a `Build Environment variables` with the name `WEBHOOKS` with an url as value.

Then in my function I'm trying to read the variable like this:

`webhooks = os.environ.get('WEBHOOKS')`

when printing the output it returns `None`

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of [build environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#cloud-console-ui_3) is providing configuration information to the underlying build system.

Please, use instead [runtime environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#using_runtime_environment_variables), accesible to the code at runtime.

You can define them in the [Cloud Console UI](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/env-var#setting_runtime_environment_variables) as well.

Comment: ok thanks a lot. I read about this but didn't notice the differences on the UI... pretty obvious...

Comment: You are welcome Simon, I am very happy to hear that the answer was helpful.